# Apple ARKit Coordinate Space Mismatch with VRM Model

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, coordinate-transformation, gltf

I am working on face tracking with Swift Arkit using a VRM model, but the model I imported looks backwards (reversed Z-axis) and the rotations are working in reverse. As far as I understand VRM uses [right-handed Y-UP](https://vrm.dev/en/docs/univrm/programming/univrm_coordinate/) (OpenGL standard) coordinate space, but ARKit uses left-hand Y-UP. How can I sync these two systems and run the tracking properly. Thanks!

```
//Imported model is added to ARSCNView 
open class AvatarView: ARSCNView {
  ...
  private func setUp(node: VRMNode) {
    let scene = SCNScene()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    self.scene = scene
  }
 ...
}

//Render the head node of the model for face tracking.
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    guard anchor is ARFaceAnchor else { return nil }

    return self.avatarView.avatar.humanoid.node(for: .head)
}

}
```